# How to pass a list and a string to one view from two actions of one controller? How to get this data separately in view file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view, model, controller

**Please see this code of index.cshtml below:-**

List is displayed like below & The string is the Caption, for which i send the company ID to Controller

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Company 

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Template)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caption)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CompanyID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CompanyID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CompanyID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>       

    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetCaption", "Company", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("txtCmpID")
        <input id="btnGetCaption" type="submit" value="Get Caption" />
    }
    <span style="color: Black; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 20px;">
        @text = 
    </span>
```

**Code inside Controller.cs file:-**

```
private DynaPortalContext db = new DynaPortalContext();

    //
    // GET: /Company/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Companies.ToList());
    }
    //
    // GET: /Company/caption
    [ActionName("GetCaption"),HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCaption(string txtCmpID)
    {
        Company company = db.Companies.Find(txtCmpID);
        return View("Index",company);
    }
```

Please tell me how to display the resulting caption from the GetCaption() method of controller into the view in @text=...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GetCaption` method isn't actually getting a caption, it's getting a company. Assuming that the `Company` contains the `Caption` that you're looking for, you can simply display the `Caption` property inside the span:

```
<span style="color: Black; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 20px;">@Model.Caption</span>
```

Also, why are you including a textbox in your form when you're using Get rather than Post? If you're not posting that value back to the server, it's redundant and misleading to use an input capturing element here. You'd be better off using a span, the same way you are with the caption.

The convention with MVC is to create Views with the same name as their corresponding controller actions. In your case, you have 2 different controller actions that both return the same view, `Index`. In the `Index` controller action, you pass a list of companies as the model. In the `GetCaption` controller action, you pass a single controller action to the same `Index` view, which won't work. It looks like you want a second view to handle the `GetCaption` action. It's not clear whether the second code block in your question is within the `Index` view or a different one?

Comment: What you have said is really correct, i dont need a textbox there, if i am using a static value as 5 in the Getcaption method..
But my intention was to let the user input an ID , post that value back to controller and get the result displayed into view..

Comment: Fair enough, but if you want to post that value to the controller, you will need to use HttpPost in your controller action. If you want to use HttpGet, you'll need to pass the value via the querystring. I still don't understand how the page is supposed to work. Could you explain the requirement?

Comment: The requirement is to display the list of companies and the caption string in one view. For Caption user has to input the ID value in textbox.

Comment: And then what? Once the user enters an id, what should they see?

Comment: Then the view gets updated with the caption string , but the list remains as such..

Comment: Have you considered making an ajax request to get the caption?